# Goodstein's theorem without transfinite induction

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, reference-request

[Goodstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) is an example of a theorem that is not provable from first order arithmetic. All proofs of the theorem seem to deploy transfinite induction and I've wondered if one could prove the theorem without transfinite induction. Some time ago I came across [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130604052023/http://www.math.niu.edu/%7Erusin/known-math/00_incoming/goodstein) old usenet post where Torkel Franzen writes

> Goodstein's
> theorem does not necessarily require transfinite induction for its
> proof, but it's not provable in elementary arithmetic. It can be
> proved by ordinary induction on a statement involving quantification
> over sets...

What is the proof/statement Franzen is referring to?

Comment: Note, that Goodstein can be proven in second order logic. So, if the sets are defined by predicates and you allow quantification over it, you have effectively a second order system. The proof in such system might however become close to the transfinite proof. 

Comment: Interesting! Have you checked Franzen's *Inexhaustibility* book? Sounds like this is a concrete way to see that $ACA_0$ with $\Sigma^1_1$-induction is not conservative over $PA$.

Comment: I have been thinking how exactly the second order proof goes. One should prove that if the exponents follow a well ordered relation, then the newly created relation is also well ordered. Which such proof, you can then do induction on the height of the exponent tower. Because, we are quantifying over all well ordered relations, this is a second order proof. In case of meta-logic (using Constructive omega rule), the quantification is on syntactical level.

Comment: I'm out of the office so I can't check but Google books tells me there are four matches for "Goodstein" in the book (one of which is in the index). So I think it's worth a trip to the library.

Comment: Perhaps this post is relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/354551/121665.

Answer (score 5):

I am quite convinced that Goodstein's theorem can be proven with the constructive omega rule. Or "meta-logic". For every individual 'n' Goodstein's theorem can be proven in elementary arithmetic (the problem is the quantification). In a meta-proof you can prove that for every 'n' such valid proof can be generated. I believe that this "meta-proof" only requires elementary arithmetic (if the meta-proof would require second order logic, then we wouldn't have achieved anything).

Of course, I can only claim this by detailing this out, but given my understanding of the Goodstein theorem, I am quite convinced that it should be possible.

Comment: But the way that your prove it for each $n$ is essentially by transfinite induction up to the particular ordinal represented by replacing $2$ with $\omega$ in the complete base $2$ representation of $n$. The point is that PA is strong enough to prove that the corresponding relation is a well-order for each specific $n$ separately, but not that the full relation, corresponding to ordinal $\epsilon_0$, is a well-order.

Comment: Joel, I am not quite following your comment. As said, I am quite convinced that Goodman can be proven in FOL + PA + COR, (but it is a more than year ago that I have thought about it). Are you saying that this is incorrect or that this is similar to transfinite induction? 

Comment: I am saying that the proof in that system that I know is essentially the transfinite proof (but using codes for the ordinals as natural numbers). That is, to prove instance $n$ in PA, you in effect interpret $n$ as coding an ordinal, and use the fact that PA can prove that there is no infinite descending sequence of ordinals starting from that code.

Comment: See  W. Buchholz and S.S Wainer "Provably Computable Functions and the Fast Growing Hierarchy", 1987