# Could Kronecker accept a proof of Goodstein's theorem?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, peano-arithmetic

A famous result of Goodstein asserts that the Goodstein sequence of integers terminates. 
For a precise statement and a short proof, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem.

A well known proof of this theorem uses ordinal number. The idea is to associate with the Goodstein sequence a sequence of ordinal numbers that is decreasing and every decreasing sequence of ordinal numbers terminates after a finite number of steps.

A well-known result of Kirby and Paris asserts that Goodstein's theorem cannot be proved in the Peano arithmetic. My vague understanding is (correct if I am wrong) that any proof of the Goodstein theorem would require a proof of existence of the ordinal number
$$
\large \omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^{\omega^\ldots}}}}
$$
and such a large number cannot be constructed in the Peano arithmetic.

I believe this result is of wide interest in the mathematical community. While there have been a lot of discussions related to this theorem on Mathoverflow, the theorem is set deeply in foundations of mathematics and most of the discussions are so hermetic that only people with good understanding of the foundations of mathematics can follow it. I have some working knowledge in the area (as most of us do), but that restricts to a basic understanding of ZFC, practical use of the axiom of choice, and some understanding of basic results in arithmetic of ordinal numbers. With such a limited knowledge I am not able to follow the discussions.

Georg Cantor created foundations of the modern set theory. However, his theory encountered a strong resistance from prominent mathematicians including Kronecker, Poincaré, Weyl and Brouwer. Kronecker described Cantor as a "scientific charlatan", a "renegade" and a "corrupter of youth".

Without the set theory created by Cantor, the proof of Goodstein's theorem based on the arithmetic of ordinal numbers would not exist and hence the known proof would not be accepted by Kronecker, Poincaré, Weyl or Brouwer.

Therefore my question is:

> **Question.** Is it possible to prove Goodstein's theorem in an "elementary" way so that it would be accepted by Kronecker?

I have heard that there are "elementary", but rather long proofs using second-order arithmetic (I do not even know what it means).

> **Question.** Where can I find a proof that does not involve ordinal numbers?

Since I find these questions of great interest for everyone, I would appreciate a detailed and "elementary" explanation. For example while referring to the second-order arithmetic I would appreciate if someone could explain in details what it really means by showing some examples.

**Edit:** I replaced Gauss with Kronecker in the question. It seems a better choice.

Comment: There are some pretty concrete ways to think of induction up to $\epsilon_0$. Gauss was pretty smart. I'd bet he could handle it.

Comment: @AaronBergman Can you be a more concrete and expand it into an answer how to prove Goodstein's theorem?

Comment: It’s pretty intuitive (to me at least) to construct ordinals up to $\epsilon_0$ “by hand” as von Neumann ordinals. Higher up, things get scary, but this isn’t so bad. There’s also the classic hydra game for a combinatorial description.

Comment: It seems to me there is a lot of noise in the question. I don't see why Gauss would have any trouble with the standard proof.

Comment: @Andrés: Other than the fact that he's been dead for a few centuries, you mean? :)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Cantor proved existence of transcendental numbers as a consequence of the fact that there are only countably many algebraic ones. That is a perfectly fine proof, but it had not been accepted as a proof by the community.   Why would the case of Goodstein's theorem be different. How about instead of Gauss I put Kronecker?

Comment: @Piotr Let's not rewrite history, please.

Comment: By mentioning Kronecker, you implicitly introduce the issue of *constructiveness* of the proof, a very interesting issue.

Comment: What don't you understand in the Wikipedia article on second-order arithmetic? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic) It differs from first-order arithmetic in including quantification over sets, and Wikipedia's section on syntax has good examples of second-order statements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is really an expansion of Aaron Bergman and others' comments as well as information that exists on the Wikipedia articles on [Goodstein's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) and [epsilon numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)). I will sketch a proof of Goodstein's theorem and you'll have to tell me if Kronecker would have accepted it as a legitimate argument. (I'm not sure if this is the best 'elementary looking' proof and I don't know if this would be considered a long proof. If somebody knows a simpler proof that looks elementary please tell me. I'm also not sure how constructive this argument can be. As written it certainly isn't.)

Let $T$ be the collection of finite rooted trees. For each natural number $n$, let $T_n \subset T$ be the collection of rooted finite trees of height at most $n$ (we'll say that the rooted tree with a single node has height $0$).

We will define a linear order $\sqsubset$ on $T$ inductively by defining it on each $T_n$. $T_0$ has a single element, so the order on $T_0$ is the trivial order. Now for any $n$, given the order on $T_n$, for any $a \in T_{n+1}$ we can associate a finite sequence of elements of $T_n$, which we'll write $s(a)$, by listing the children of the root note of $a$ in descending order according to $\sqsubset$ (which we have already defined). Given $a,b \in T_{n+1}$, we say that $a\sqsubset b$ if $a\neq b$ and at the first index $i$ at which $s(a)$ and $s(b)$ differ, either $s(a)(i)$ doesn't exist or it does and $s(a)(i) \sqsubset s(b)(i)$.

It is not hard to show that $\sqsubset$ is a linear order on $T_{n+1}$, that $\sqsubset$ as defined in $T_{n+1}$ agrees with $\sqsubset$ as defined on $T_n$, and that $T_n$ is an initial segment of $T_{n+1}$ under $\sqsubset$. Therefore we can treat $\sqsubset$ as a linear order on all of $T$. Note that while $T$ is an infinite set, the elements of $T$ are finite objects (and can be coded by natural numbers) and the relation $a\sqsubset b$ is computable.

> **Lemma.** For any $n$, if $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T_n$ is non-increasing under $\sqsubset$, then it is eventually constant.

*Proof.* We will show this by induction on $n$. The proposition is obvious for $n=0$. Assume that we've shown it for $T_{n}$ and let $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T_{n+1}$ be a non-increasing function. Clearly if $f(k)$ is ever the unique element of $T_0$, then we're done, so assume that $f(k)$ is never in $T_0$.

*Claim:* For every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, the partial function $k \mapsto s(f(k))(i)$ is eventually constant (i.e. either eventually always defined and a constant value or eventually always undefined).

*Proof of claim.* We will prove this by induction on $i$. For $i = 0$, we have that $k \mapsto s(f(k))(0)$ is a non-increasing function whose codomain is $T_n$. By the overall induction hypothesis (on $n$), this implies that $k \mapsto s(f(k))(0)$ is eventually constant.

Assume that we've shown the claim for some $i$ and consider the partial function $k \mapsto s(f(k))(i+1)$. If $k \mapsto s(f(k))(i)$ is eventually always undefined, then $k \mapsto s(f(k))(i+1)$ is also eventually always undefined and we're done, so assume that $k \mapsto s(f(k))(i)$ is eventually always defined and let it be constant on inputs larger than $m$. Consider $k \mapsto s(f(m + k))(i+1)$. If this is ever undefined, then it is undefined for any larger inputs as well, so assume that it is always defined. In this case, we have that this is a non-increasing function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $T_n$, so by the overall induction hypothesis we have that it must eventually be constant as well. So in both cases it is eventually constant.

Therefore by induction, $k \mapsto s(f(k))(i)$ is eventually constant for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, as required. $\square_{\text{claim}}$

For each $i$, let $g(i)$ be the eventual value of the map $k \mapsto s(f(k))(i)$ (where we take $g(i)$ to be undefined if $s(f(k))(i)$ is undefined for sufficiently large $k$). We have that $g(i)$ is defined on an initial segment of the natural numbers, possibly all of them. Furthermore, since $s(a)$ is always in decreasing order, we have that $g(i)$ is a non-increasing partial function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $T_n$. This means that if $g(i)$ is defined for all $i$, by the induction hypothesis we have that it is eventually constant.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $g(i)$ is defined for all $i$. Let $a$ be its eventual value and let $j$ be some index such that $g(j) = a$. Choose $m$ such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $s(f(m+k))(j) = a$. Since $k \mapsto s(f(m+k))(j)$ is constant, we have that $k\mapsto s(f(m+k))(j+1)$ is non-increasing, and in particular must be defined for all $k$, otherwise $g(j+1)$ would be undefined. By construction we have that $s(f(m))(j+1) \leq s(f(m))(j)$, so since the eventual value of $k \mapsto s(f(m))(j+1)$ is also $a$, we must actually have $s(f(m+k))(j+1) = a$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Iterating this argument shows by induction that for any $\ell \geq j$, $s(f(m+k))(\ell) = a$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, so in particular $s(f(m))(\ell) = a$ for all $\ell \geq j$, but this contradicts the fact that $s(f(m))$ is a finite string.

Therefore $g(i)$ is undefined for all but finitely many $i$. Let $j$ be the largest such that for all $i \leq j$, $g(i)$ is defined. Find $m$ such that $s(f(m+k))(i)$ is constant for all $i \leq j$ and is always undefined for $i = j+1$. Since $s(f(m+k))(j+1)$ is always undefined, we have that $s(f(m+k))(\ell)$ is always undefined for any $\ell > j$, which implies that $k \mapsto f(m+k)$ is in fact a constant map, so we have that $f$ is eventually constant, as required. $\square$

Now from this lemma we immediately get that if $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T$ is non-increasing under $\sqsubset$, then it is eventually constant, because each $T_n$ is an initial segment of $T$ and $f(0) \in T_n$ for some $n$. (Of course this is just the fact that $\varepsilon_0$ is well-ordered expressed with a particular notation for elements of $\varepsilon_0$, but I won't tell Kronecker if you don't.)

At this point the rest of the proof should be fairly familiar. Given any Goodstein sequence, $g_n$, we associate a sequence of elements of $T$ by converting the hereditary base-$(n+2)$ notation representation of $g_n$ to a finite rooted tree by the following: $0$ corresponds to the tree with a single node and the number $a_k (n+2)^k + a_{k-1} (n+2)^{k-1} + \dots + a_0$ corresponds to a tree where for each $\ell \leq k$, we attach $a_\ell$ copies of the tree associated to $\ell$ to the root node. It is clear that replacing $n+2$ by $n+3$ does not change the associated tree, but subtracting $1$ does produce a strictly smaller tree under $\sqsubset$. If we had a Goodstein sequence which did not terminate it would give us a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T$ which was non-increasing but also not eventually constant, which contradicts our lemma. Therefore every Goodstein sequence must terminate.

---

Regarding the metamathematical properties of this proof, the place where we are using second order arithmetic is in the main induction in the lemma, because the statement is for all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T_n$, which is using a second-order quantifier. The thing is that we don't really need this full strength for Goodstein's theorem. It is good enough to know it for computable $f$ (since the function associated to a Goodstein sequence is computable), but note that in the inductive proof we use the induction hypothesis on $g(i)$, which is not a priori a computable function, even when $f$ itself is. Furthermore, even though $g(i)$ is in general only a partial function with finite domain (and hence a computable object), this is non-uniform. If we have a family of functions $f_p: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T_n$ and we want to know the associated family $g_p(i)$, this will typically require the Turing jump of the family $f_p$ to compute. This is a sign that these proofs won't work very uniformly in Peano arithmetic, especially since unpacking a proof of the lemma for a specific $n$ will end up needing something like $n$ Turing jumps.

We can formalize an encoding of finite rooted trees as natural numbers in Peano arithmetic and prove many basic properties (e.g. everything before the lemma). For any finite $n$ and any family $f_p(k)$ of uniformly definable functions $f_p : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T_n$, Peano arithmetic proves the following:

> For any parameter $p$, if $f_p : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow T_n$ is non-increasing, then it is eventually constant.

The whole issue is that $\mathsf{PA}$ cannot prove this uniformly in $n$ for sufficiently complicated families $f_p$, such as, for instance, the family of computable functions.

Comment: In a nutshell: if you accept that PA is consistent, you can prove Goodstein's theorem.

Comment: @NikWeaver No, you can’t. (PA+Con(PA) accepts that PA is consistent, but doesn’t prove Goodstein’s theorem. You’d need to accept that PA is $\Sigma_1$-sound.) Regardless, this has nothing to do with the proof James Hanson presented, which does not involve anything related to the consistency of PA.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. No, I was not summarizing James's proof, but if you look at his final point I think you'll see the connection: if we accept that everything PA proves is true, then we can accept that Goodstein's theorem is true.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I still have to read it more carefully. I am too busy now with closing of the University of Pittsburgh. As a graduate director I have to figure out how to handle this situation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot yo accept your answer and vote it up. I thought I had it done already.

Answer (score 9):

As a starting point, I recommend that you study the proof of Theorem 1 in my expository article on [The Consistency of Arithmetic](http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/consistent.pdf). (This is not exactly a proof of Goodstein's theorem, but for the purposes of the present discussion I think it's close enough. Start reading on page 25 where it says "Ordinals below $\epsilon_0$.")

I have tried to make this proof as "pedestrian" as possible, avoiding concepts from logic and set theory that might be unfamiliar to the "working mathematician."  In particular, my contention is that if you were to present this proof in (say) an undergraduate analysis class, it would seem completely unobjectionable and unremarkable.  True, the proof assumes that it is meaningful to talk about infinite sequences, but infinite sequences are routinely bandied about in undergraduate analysis without comment.  Also, the induction argument is trickier than most induction arguments, but I don't think that anyone would find anything suspicious about it unless they had been specifically told to look for something suspicious.

Sometimes the terms "PA proof" and "elementary proof" are used interchangeably.  I think that this practice can lead to confusion.  The class of proofs that are formalizable in PA is of course a very clearly defined class, but it does not correspond very closely to what we *intuitively* think of as "elementary" proofs.  In particular, the $\epsilon_0$ upper bound is, from the point of view of ordinary mathematical practice, a rather artificial bound.  For example, we know from reverse mathematics that in a certain precise sense, the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem goes beyond PA, but in our undergraduate analysis classes we don't set out flares or start blaring emergency sirens when proving Bolzano–Weierstrass.  The exact logical strength of various assumptions that are used in ordinary mathematics is something that is not apparent on the surface, and emerges only after a careful logical analysis.

Conversely, it's possible to encode highly sophisticated concepts and proofs in PA—concepts that most mathematicians would instinctively regard as being "not at all elementary."  **EDIT** (in light of the comments): For example, sometimes people ask if Fermat's Last Theorem can be proved in PA.  I think that most of them are implicitly trying to ask whether there is an *elementary* proof of FLT.  But as Angus Macintyre has shown (see comments below), it is very likely that all the high-falutin' super-fancy "non-elementary" machinery used in the known proof of FLT can be sufficiently well approximated in PA to push the proof through.  If Macintyre is right, which I think he is, then this would show that FLT is provable in PA, while leaving completely unanswered the question of whether there is an "elementary" proof of FLT.

Returning to the question of Gauss or Kronecker, it's a little tough to guess what they would have thought about these things.  They might have affirmed that they believed in "potential infinity" and not "actual infinity," but most modern mathematicians regard these two terms as philosophical gobbledygook, making it hard to translate Gauss's beliefs directly into present-day terms.  We can probably safely say that they would have balked at ZFC, in particular the axiom of infinity, but the axiom of infinity isn't absolutely necessary for Goodstein's theorem.
Indeed, Gentzen, in his proof of the consistency of PA, made an effort to argue that the reasoning was "finitary."  Since "finitary" isn't a completely precise term either, it's hard to be sure that Gauss would have agreed with Gentzen, but it's at least plausible that he would have.  Ultimately, like all historical counterfactuals, it's a matter of speculation what Gauss would have thought.  But hopefully I've convinced you that there isn't anything more mysterious about Goodstein's theorem than many other routine mathematical theorems.

Comment: "it's possible to encode highly sophisticated concepts and proofs in PA" <--- would the theorem Con(ZF) => Con(ZFC+not CH) be an example?

Comment: @DavidRoberts : Yes, that could count, although what I had in mind was more along the lines of Angus Macintyre's appendix to Chapter 1 ("The Impact of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems on Mathematics") of *Kurt Gödel and the Foundations of Mathematics: Horizons of Truth*, where he sketches a plan for encoding the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem in PA.

Comment: @TimothyChow But that's *much* harder than proving Con(ZF)=>Con(ZFC+not CH) in PA.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : Agreed. That's why I think it's a better illustration of what I meant by "highly sophisticated concepts" that are "not at all elementary."

Comment: "most modern mathematicians regard these two terms as philosophical gobbledygook". Tim, the distinction between the two types of infinity goes back at least to Aristoteles, and was understood for two millenia. What exactly is the gobbledygook?

Comment: @MircoA.Mannucci : I'm not saying that the terms are _actually_ gobbledygook, just that most modern mathematicians _regard_ them as gobbledygook. The distinction between potential and actual infinity never occurs in modern technical papers in mathematics. There is no generally accepted _mathematical_ definition of the distinction between potential and actual infinity.