Does Peano's axioms prove $\alpha$-induction for primitive recursive sequences for every concrete $\alpha < \varepsilon_0$?
It is well-known that Peano's axioms (PA) cannot prove $\varepsilon_0$-induction for primitive recursive sequences (PRWO($\varepsilon_0$)), because PA + PRWO($\varepsilon_0$) proves the consistency of PA. As explicitly shown in "Goodstein Revisited" by Michael Rathjen, PRWO($\varepsilon_0$) is actually equivalent to Goodstein's theorem — the "special" version where the base sequence goes 2, 3, 4, ... Obviously PA does prove that each concrete special Goodstein sequence terminates: Since the sequence is in fact finite, one could just write it down as the proof.
However, Goodstein's original paper in fact considers "general" Goodstein sequences where the base sequence $\{b_n\}$ can be arbitrary, and proved their termination for $m \le b_1^{b_1^{b_1}}$ with a "finitist" proof. As Bernays pointed out (and Rathjen called attention to), the statement Goodstein proved cannot be formulated in PA due to the inability to express an arbitrary sequence $\{b_n\}$, let alone the proof. However, (my understanding is that) restricting $\{b_n\}$ to primitive recursive sequences allows the proof to be formulated in PA, which is also essentially a proof of PRWO($\omega^{\omega^\omega}$) in PA.
Goodstein also claimed, despite Bernays' criticism, that a "finitist" proof can be given for concrete larger ordinals such as $\vartheta_3 = \omega^{\omega^{\omega^\omega}}$, $\vartheta_4 = \omega^{\vartheta_3}$, etc. If we interpret "finitist" as "the version restricted to primitive recursive $\{b_n\}$ is a proof in PA", is Goodstein's claim actually justified? If so, is there a simple argument to show that?

One way to express an 'arbitrary sequence' is moving to second-order arithmetic (in this case, $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ since it is a conservative extension of $\mathsf{PA}$.) Then we can quantify over sequences, which will give a $\Pi^1_1$-assertion. We can bring an $\mathsf{ACA}_0$-theorem of the form $\forall X \phi(X)$ to a theorem of $\mathsf{PA}$ by replacing $X$ to an arithmetical formula (e.g., instantiate $\forall X \phi(X)$ with $X={n\mid \psi(n)}$ for an arithmetical $\psi$.)

Also, the title of your question asks about $\alpha$-induction, but your question in your post is proving Goodstein's theorem for specific sequences. May I ask which question you really wanted to ask?

It may be worth to mention that PA proves full induction for each well ordering $\alpha < \varepsilon_0$. The result is presented, e.g., in a textbook by Kotlarski, A Model–Theoretic Approach to Proof Theory (Theorem 4.1), attributed to Gentzen.

@KonradZdanowski I found the book (it was Theorem 4.2.1 on my version). It seems to me that the proof is "non-uniform" not only in the initial ordinal but also in the level of the arithmetical hierarchy the formula is at. However this does answer my problem about PR induction since even general inductive functions are in $\Delta_0$. Furthermore the proof seems pretty self-contained. I'll take a closer look.

There's also a gorgeous proof in Berger's "Program Extraction from Gentzen’s Proof of Transfinite Induction up to $\varepsilon_0$"

@ImperishableNight Yes, this is a family of proofs parametrized by the complexity of assumed induction, the complexity of proven induction and the length of induction in terms of ordinals $\omega_n$. Though, these proofs are quite similar and could be expressed in an extended language with a new predicate $P$ as getting $\omega_{n+1}$-induction for $P$ from $\omega_{n+1}$-induction for $\Sigma_1(P)$.

I suppose you asked proving Goodstein's theorem for a given primitive recursive base sequence $\langle b_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ (that is, the $(n+1)$th element of the Goodstein sequence is obtained from the $n$th element by subtracting 1 and replacing $b_n$ to $b_{n+1}$ in its hereditary base-$b_n$-notation) with the fixed initial number terminates over $\mathsf{PA}$. As I stated in the comment, we can prove it by moving to a second-order arithmetic and bringing its result to the first-order counterpart.
It is well-known that Arithmetical Comprehension Axiom $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ is a conservative extension of $\mathsf{PA}$: That is, every first-order statement (i.e., statements with no quantifiers for reals) provable in $\mathsf{PA}$ is also provable over $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, and vice versa.
Now let us prove the following: Fix a (standard) natural number $a_0$. Then for every sequence $\vec{b}$, the Goodstein sequence $\langle a_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ with the base sequence $\vec{b}$ starting from $n$ terminates. Its proof is more or less similar to the proof for Goodstein's theorem with ordinals, but the problem is that we do not have ordinals in second-order arithmetic.
But observe that in the standard proof, we map each term of a Goodstein sequence $a_n$ an ordinal $\xi_n<\varepsilon_0$, which is strictly decreasing until it reaches $0$. Furthermore, we can still define a recursive linear order $L$ that looks similar to $\varepsilon_0$, which is indeed isomorphic to $\varepsilon_0$ if we assume set theory. Thus we can carry over the same proof with this linear order by mapping each element of the Goodstein sequence $a_n$ to an element of the linear order $\xi_n\in L$.
We do not know if $L$ is well-founded, and $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ cannot prove if $L$ is well-founded. (It is equivalent to the $\Pi^1_1$-soundness of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, which is stronger than the consistency of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$.) However, $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ proves for each (standard) natural number $m$, the initial segment of $L$ by $m$ is well-founded. It roughly corresponds to the '$\alpha$-induction for $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$' you stated in the title.
We fixed $a_0$ by a standard natural number, so we can calculate the natural number coding $\xi_0$ which is also standard. $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ proves $\{\eta\in L\mid \eta<\xi_0\}$ is well-founded, so $\langle \xi_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ must be eventually zero.
Thus, we get a theorem of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$. To get a theorem of $\mathsf{PA}$, we instantiate the $\mathsf{ACA}_0$-theorem by replacing $\vec{b}$ to a specific primitive recursive sequence. In fact, we can do more: $\vec{b}$ can be not only primitive recursive but also arithmetical, i.e., there is a first-order formula defining $\vec{b}$. The resulting instantiation is a first-order statement, so the conservativity result shows $\mathsf{PA}$ proves what we wanted to prove.

Regarding the well-foundedness of the initial segment of $\varepsilon_0$, it follows from the following two results:

Proposition. $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ proves transfinite induction for arithmetical formulas. That is, if $\phi(x,X)$ is an arithmetical formula and $\alpha$ is a well-order, then
$$[\forall\xi\in\alpha\;[(\forall\eta<_\alpha\xi\;\phi(\eta,X)) \to \phi(\xi,X)]] \to \forall \xi\in\alpha
\;\phi(\xi,X).$$
Here $X$ is a parameter real.
Proof. Suppose that the above fails. Consider the set $A=\{\xi\in\alpha\mid \lnot\phi(\xi,X)\}$ that exists by Arithmetical Comprehension. $A$ is not empty, so we can choose its minimal element $\xi_0$. But then we can see that $\xi_0\notin A$.


Theorem. $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ proves if $\alpha$ is a well-order, then $\omega^\alpha$ is also a well-order.

Then we can see that every initial segment of $\varepsilon_0 = \sup \{\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega},\cdots\}$ (given by the standard integer) is well-founded. You are right that the proof for the well-foundedness cannot be uniform, otherwise, $\mathsf{ACA}_0$ would prove the well-foundedness of $\varepsilon_0$.

Proof of the theorem. We can prove more: If $\alpha$ is well-ordered, then $\omega^\alpha$ satisfies transfinite induction for arithmetical formulas. Before stating the proof, note that elements of $\omega^\alpha$ take the form $\omega^{\xi_0}+\cdots+\omega^{\xi_{m-1}}$ for $\xi_0\ge\cdots\ge\xi_{m-1}$ in $\alpha$.
Let $\phi(x,X)$ be an arithmetical formula such that
$$\forall x \in\omega^\alpha\; [\forall y<_{\omega^\alpha}x\; \phi(y,X)]\to \phi(x,X).$$
Let us define
$$\psi(x,X) \equiv \forall u\in\omega^\alpha [\forall z<_{\omega^\alpha} u\ \phi(z,X)\to \forall z<_{\omega^\alpha} u+\omega^x\; \phi(z,X).]$$
Then $\psi(x,X)$ is also arithmetical. Moreover, we can see that for every $x\in \alpha$, the following holds:
$$\forall y<_\alpha x\; \psi(y,X)\to \psi(x,X).$$
It is clear when $x$ is 0 or a limit. Thus consider the successor case: Suppose that we have $\psi(x,X)$. We want to show $\psi(x+1,X)$. To do this, let us fix $u$ and consider the following formula:
$$\chi(n,u,X)\equiv \forall z<_{\omega^\alpha} u+\omega^x\cdot n\; \phi(z,X).$$
We can prove $\forall n\ \chi(n,u,X)$ by induction on $n$: The case $n=0$ is clear. And if $\chi(n,u,X)$ holds, then $\psi(x,X)$ implies
$$\forall z<_{\omega^\alpha} u+\omega^x\cdot n\ \phi(z,X)\to \forall z<_{\omega^\alpha} u+\omega^x\cdot n+\omega^x\ \phi(z,X).$$
So we get $\chi(n+1,u,X)$.
Hence $\forall n\;\chi(n,u,X)$ holds. Sicne $u$ is arbitrary, we have $\psi(x+1,X)$.


To clarify: We don't need to choose a fixed base sequence when lowering the proof to PA, is that right?

So I went through the answer again, and realized that the statement "$\mathsf{ACA}_0$ proves for each (standard) natural number $m$, the initial segment of $L$ by $m$ is well-founded" is the part I am actually wondering about. What does a proof for this fact look like?

Actually, is the proof you are referring to something like https://mathoverflow.net/a/354668/527757?

@ImperishableNight You are right that we can choose the base sequence arbitrarily, although the initial term of the Goodstein must be fixed to a standard natural number. Regarding the well-foundedness of initial segments of $L$, I will add its proof.

@ImperishableNight I haven't checked Hanson's proof in detail, but it should be similar to my proof as we can understand ordinals below $\varepsilon_0$ as a finite rooted tree if we interpret $\omega^{\alpha_0}+\cdots+\omega^{\alpha_{n-1}}$ as a rooted tree with $n$ children and the $i$th child attaches a tree corresponding to $\alpha_i$.

I feel that the source of the non-uniformity is actually in proving $\chi(n, X) \to \chi(n+1, X)$, so it might help to spell out the proof of that part.

@ImperishableNight I don't think it is the source of the nonuniformity. I think the source is that to get a well-foundness of $\omega^{\omega^\omega}$, for example, we must apply the theorem $\mathsf{WO}(\alpha)\to \mathsf{WO}(\omega^\alpha)$ two times, and for the well-foundedness of towers of $(n+1)$ many $\omega$, we need to apply the theorem $n$ times.

@ImperishableNight It looks like my proof is not quite correct. Let me fix it with some additional details.
